# mock boto3 response for downloading file from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I've got code that downloads a file from an S3 bucket using [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file).

```py
# foo.py
def dl(src_f, dest_f):
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  s3.Bucket('mybucket').download_file(src_f, dest_f)
```

I'd now like to write a unit test for `dl()` using pytest and by mocking the interaction with AWS using the stubber available in [botocore](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html).

```py
@pytest.fixture
def s3_client():
    yield boto3.client("s3")

from foo import dl
def test_dl(s3_client):

  with Stubber(s3_client) as stubber:
    params = {"Bucket": ANY, "Key": ANY}
    response = {"Body": "lorem"}
    stubber.add_response(SOME_OBJ, response, params)
    dl('bucket_file.txt', 'tmp/bucket_file.txt')
    assert os.path.isfile('tmp/bucket_file.txt')
```

I'm not sure about the right approach for this. How do I add `bucket_file.txt` to the stubbed reponse? What object do I need to `add_response()` to (shown as `SOME_OBJ`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you considered using [moto3](https://github.com/spulec/moto)?
Your code could look the same way as it is right now:

```py
# foo.py
def dl(src_f, dest_f):
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  s3.Bucket('mybucket').download_file(src_f, dest_f)
```

and the test:

```py
import boto3
import os
from moto import mock_s3

@mock_s3
def test_dl():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
    # We need to create the bucket since this is all in Moto's 'virtual' AWS account
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket='mybucket')
    
    s3.put_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key= 'bucket_file.txt', Body='')
    dl('bucket_file.txt', 'bucket_file.txt')

    assert os.path.isfile('bucket_file.txt')
```

The intention of the code becomes a bit more obvious since you simply work with s3 as usual, except for there is no real s3 behind the method calls.

Comment: Are you missing the declaration for `s3`? e.g. `s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')`

Comment: My bad, it is fixed now.

Comment: Is there any convenience constructor that can construct a s3 mock using moto with a directory of files representing the prefilled s3 bucket?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai hmmm... not that I know.