# Mock download file from s3 with actual file

Tags: python, unit-testing, boto3, moto

I would like to write a test to mock the download of a function from s3 and replace it locally with an actual file that exists of my machine. I took inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564394/mock-boto3-response-for-downloading-file-from-s3). The idea is the following:

```
from moto import mock_s3
import boto3

def dl(src_f, dest_f):
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  s3.Bucket('fake_bucket').download_file(src_f, dest_f)

@mock_s3
def _create_and_mock_bucket():

    # Create fake bucket and mock it
    bucket = "fake_bucket"

    # We need to create the bucket since this is all in Moto's 'virtual' AWS account
    file_path = "some_real_file.txt"
    s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket)
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_path, Body="")

    dl(file_path, 'some_other_real_file.txt')

_create_and_mock_bucket()
```

Now `some_other_real_file.txt` exists, but it is not a copy of `some_real_file.txt`. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'some_real_file.txt' already exists on your system, you should use upload_file instead:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

For your example:

```py
file_path = "some_real_file.txt"
s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket)
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.meta.client.upload_file(file_path, bucket, file_path)
```

Your code currently creates an empty file in S3 (since Body=""), and that is exactly what is being downloaded to 'some_other_real_file.txt'.
Notice that, if you change the Body-parameter to have some text in it, that exact content will be downloaded to 'some_other_real_file.txt'.